# How to reverse geocode an array of co-ordinates at once from Google Place API?

Tags: google-maps, web-services, google-places-api

When I try place API, it only allows one co-ordinate set at a time and if I send so many requests at once they are blocking my request. Is there a way to reverse geocode a bunch of lat/longs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoding web requests (server-side) are meant for batch processing. According to the [usage limits documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits), Geocoding has 50 requests per second (QPS), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries. So first, check if you have the correct default limits set by going to your [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard):

1. Go to your dashboard: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard and click "Go to API's overview"
2. Select Geocoding API
3. Click quotas
4. Under the “Requests” section at the very bottom you will find the API's limits

If you see the "Request per Minute" set to 3,000 (3000 calls/60 sec= 50 calls /sec.) and the "Requests per day" is unlimited, and sure that you are using your own API Key from your project that is attached to a Billing account, then there are no issues in the API but rather, with your implementation as you are just exceeding the correct limit. I would therefore recommend that you implement [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/web-service-best-practices#exponential-backoff).

If however you see lower limits mentioned, then you might be a case of one of the following:

- Using an API Key from a project that is not associated to a Billing account
- Using an API Key from a project that is associated to an INR currency Billing Account
- Have manually set per day or per minute limits

For further questions/inquiries such as these, it is best if you file a support ticket to them directly here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.